# What about implicit yield in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I often write:

`some_array.each { |array_element| array_element.some_method(args) }`

Why not have an option for an implicit yield so you could write e.g.:

`some_array.each { _.some_method(args) }`

I am not sure what character `_` should actually be, and I imagine it would only be used in the most boilerplate setting, where you're dealing with a one-dimensional array and just trying to yield each item to the block in succession. It would save a lot of redundant typing.

Comment: Interesting idea. That implementation would be a problem, but that's a detail: `class A; def a; puts 'hi'; end; end`, `_ = A.new`, _.a #=> hi`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you familiar with `#to_proc` and the `&` syntax for method calls? They cover some cases similar to the one you show here. For example:

```
[1, -2, -4].map(&:abs) => [1, 2, 4]
```

The `&` is used to pass an object in place of a block. If the object isn't a `Proc`, `#to_proc` is automatically called on it to get a `Proc` before it is used in place of the block. `Symbol#to_proc` returns a `Proc` which behaves like: `{ |obj, *args| obj.symbol_name(*args) }`.

In your example, you use `args` which are presumably captured from the surrounding lexical environment. `Symbol#to_proc` won't help you there. But it wouldn't be hard to make a new `Proc`-building method which would. For example:

```
class Symbol
  def with_args(*args)
    Proc.new { |x| x.send(self, *args) }
  end
end
```

Then you could do:

```
some_array.each(&:some_method.with_args(args))
```

Whether that is any better than an explicit block is up to you. In any case, this is a technique you should be aware of.